# Why is sscanf() is not scanning here?

Tags: c, string, struct

I have got a struct Log:

```
struct Log
{
    char message[1024];
    struct tm* time;
    char proc_name[256];
    char computer_name[256];
    int proc_pid;
};
```

I initialize it:

```
char buf[1024];
struct Log* log = malloc(sizeof(struct Log));
log->time = malloc(sizeof(struct tm));
```

And I trying to read info from string to struct Log, using this function:

```
void SyslogParse(const char* src, struct Log* log)
{
    strptime(src, "%b  %d %T", log->time);   //strptime WORK CORRECT!
    int a = sscanf(src, "%s %d %d:%d:%d %s %s[%d]: %[^\n]s", NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, &log->computer_name, &log->proc_name, &log->proc_pid, &log->message);
};
```

Or this:

```
void SyslogParse2(const char* src, struct Log* log)
{
    strptime(src, "%b  %d %T", log->time);  //strptime WORK CORRECT!
    int a = sscanf(src, "%s %d %d:%d:%d %s %s: %[^\n]s", NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, log->computer_name, log->proc_name, log->message);
};
```

Strings read from syslog file. For example:

**Jan 21 17:58:04 bogdasar-System-Product-Name anacron[786]: Job `cron.daily' terminated**

**Jan 21 17:58:24 bogdasar-System-Product-Name 05efi: debug: /dev/sda2 is a FAT32 partition**

Functions are called as follows:

```
SyslogParse2(buf, log);
```

***A problem***:
`sscanf` in `SyslogParse` functions is not working!!!

**Full code of main:**

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "DateTime.h"
#include "Log.h"
#include "Keys.h"
#define SIZE 1024

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    FILE* fl;   
    char buf[1024];     
    //time_t d = time(NULL);

    struct Keys keys;   
    struct tm* time = malloc(sizeof(struct tm));    
    struct Log* log = malloc(sizeof(struct Log));   

    log->time = malloc(sizeof(struct tm));  
    keys.time = malloc(sizeof(struct tm));  

    int opt;
    char args[] = "hd:t:";
    if(argc < 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Введите абсолютный путь к файлу\n");
        return -1;
    };

    if((fl = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Не удаётся открыть файл. Возможно его не существует. Проверьте правильность пути.\n");
        return -2;
    };

    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, args)) != -1)
    {
        switch (opt)
        {
        case 'h':
            system("cat help.txt");
            return 0;
        case 'd':
            keys.f_date = 1;
            strptime(optarg, "%b/%d", keys.time);    
            break;
        case 't':
            keys.f_time = 1;
            strptime(optarg, "%T", keys.time);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    };


    while (fgets(buf, SIZE, fl))
    {
        SyslogParse2(buf, log);

    };
    return 0;   
}
```

**Log.h**

```
#ifndef LOG
#define LOG
#define SIZE 1024
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
struct Log
{
    char message[1024];
    struct tm* time;
    char proc_name[256];
    char computer_name[256];
    int proc_pid;
};

void SyslogParse(const char* src, struct Log* log);

void SyslogParse2(const char* src, struct Log* log);
#endif
```

**Log.c**

```
#include "Log.h"
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
void SyslogParse(const char* src, struct Log* log)
{
    strptime(src, "%b  %d %T", log->time);
    int a = sscanf(src, "%s %d %d:%d:%d %s %s[%d]: %[^\n]s", NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, &log->computer_name, &log->proc_name, &log->proc_pid, &log->message);
};

void SyslogParse2(const char* src, struct Log* log)
{
    strptime(src, "%b  %d %T", log->time);
    int a = sscanf(src, "%s %d %d:%d:%d %s %s: %[^\n]s", NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, log->computer_name, log->proc_name, log->message);
};
```

***A problem***:
`sscanf` in `SyslogParse` functions is not working!!!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "is not working"?

Comment: I think you want to use assignment suppression (e.g., `"%*s"`) rather than using NULL for the argument if you want to parse but not capture a value.

Comment: @dedObed I mean structure fields are not filled after sscanf().

Comment: Of course it's "not working!!!" You're invoking undefined behavior by passing `NULL` as the target of a conversion. Per C11, [**7.21.6.2 The fscanf function**, p10](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2p10): "Unless assignment suppression was indicated by a *, the result of the conversion is placed in the object pointed to by the first argument following the format argument that has not already received a conversion result. If this object does not have an appropriate type, or if the result of the conversion cannot be represented in the object, the behavior is undefined."